Laravel 11 Mail sending to only first recipient in a loop / CC adding only X-CC header
This is using Laravel 11. I have two issues, happy to have either fixed as they’d both resolve the problem!
I’ve a loop of email addresses to send a Mail to but the first recipient is used for every message - so three addresses = three emails all to the first person.
I am using the Postmark driver and also tried Mailpit in dev.
$recipients = array_merge([config('mail.to.address')], explode(',', config('mail.cc.address')));

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    Mail::to($recipient)
        ->send(
            new ContactForm($request->except(['_token', '_slug']), $formName)
        );
}

This is as shown in the docs. My Mailable doesn’t do anything to set addresses.
If I write each Mail individually and specify the address it always uses the first one config('mail.to.address').
If I dump the recipients in Mailable buildRecipients(), I see all the addresses I want to send to.
I also tried to CC in the other emails (instead of the loop) but when I do this it adds a X-CC header to the email message, not the CC header.

So you want to send always to the same user but to add others to the cc?
You could try something like
$emails = ['user1@user1.com', 'user2@user2.com','user3@user3.com'];

Mail::send('emailView', [], function() use ($emails)
{    
    $message->to(config('mail.to.address'))->cc($emails)->subject('Some subject...');    
});

This is not tested but should work. If it does not, will reply tomorrow with tested snippet :)

My problem is CC is only adding an X-CC header to the email, not the required CC header. Happy with either CC working or separate emails. It should be really simple but for some reason just won’t work in this case.

@Ric did you try this snippet I have provided, it should work.
Other way would be to get the collection of the emails you want to contact and loop in foreach and send mails. I'd use queue in this case, instead of "->send(...)" use "->queue(...)" or just put "implements ShouldQueue" in the job and it will automatically queue those jobs for you.

I’m sending a Mailable, not using send with a view. What’s weird is I have done this many times before on other projects but this one is not working. I’ve checked config and various things but no luck.
